# How can i run my java application for virtual screens?

Tags: java, linux, swing, graphics, xorg

In Linux, we have virtual screens like desktop 1, 2, 3, 4. Most cases we use desktop 1 (screen 1, with one monitor).

Now, my question is how can i tell my java application to launch on desktop 2 (screen 2, with one monitor)

By default when i run java -cp /var/tmp/SystemX.jar run.X it will launch in desktop 1, screen 1. Which is not my case.

Tried: following but did not helped cause, it runs for dual monitor scenario. Not what i am expecting.

```
 screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
  GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
  GraphicsDevice[] screenDevices = ge.getScreenDevices();
  for (int i = 0; i < screenDevices.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(screenDevices[i].getIDstring());

    int screenWidth = 1024;
    int screenHeight = 764;
    if (screenDevices[i].getDisplayMode()!=null) {
      DisplayMode dm = screenDevices[i].getDisplayMode();
      screenWidth = dm.getWidth();
      screenHeight = dm.getHeight();        
    }
    System.out.println("[myResolution]: " + screenWidth + " " + screenHeight);
    screen.width = screenWidth;
    screen.height = screenHeight;
  }
```

**Follow up:**

```
#!/bin/sh
(export DISPLAY=:0.0 && java -cp /var/tmp/SystemX.jar run.X) & (wmctrl -r "WINDOW_TITLE" -t DESKTOP_NUMBER)
```

*** But what if my application is border less, when it has no window title ? how do i tell wmctrl ?**

Comment: Are you able start normal applications, i.e. a terminal window, on a specific screen? I'm on windows now (in office), so cannot try myself, but I think there a standard options for X11 programs for this, and I think these could be passed to the Java command line too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The borderless applications should still have window titles. (ie. xfce4-panel shows.) You can check what they are by using:

wmctrl -l

From the command line. If you're having a hard time figuring out which window is yours, try the command before you open it, then once it's open. That way, you can just look for the new window.